# Difference between a gradle dependency and an XML based dependency

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm still pretty new this...

I'm used to adding a dependencies through the grade file e.g.

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    // ...
}
```

Now I want to add a new [dependency](http://simple.sourceforge.net/maven.php), but the depedency in XML format.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Why is this code in XML, what is the difference between using Gradle, and where file in my project directory do I put this XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "XML format" is actually Maven format. That XML is how Maven identifies dependencies. Gradle dependency is the same information in a less verbose format.

In the long form, it looks like this. If you pay attention to the tags in xml and the labels here, you'll see it is the same information.

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
```

But you'll see the shorter version more commonly:

```
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
```

Learn more about gradle dependencies [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html).

Comment: Wow, great answer. I'm still having trouble getting the dependency I need, but I think I might be able to address this issue in a separate question.